# How can I access Middleman template helpers when extending a class in config.rb?

Tags: ruby, middleman

This `config.rb` works:

```
helpers do
    def link_to_nothing(text)
        link_to(text, "#")
    end
end
```

With template `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to_nothing "Test link" %>
```

But when I try to add a method to the `Middleman::Sitemap::Resource` class in this `config.rb`:

```
helpers do
    class Middleman::Sitemap::Resource
        def link(text)
            link_to(text, path)
        end
    end
end
```

With template `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= current_page.link "This page" %>
```

The following error comes up when loading the page:

> NoMethodError at /index.html
>
> undefined method `link_to' for #<Middleman::Sitemap::Resource:0x3139848>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that `link_to` is an instance method of class `Middleman::Application`, which I can access through the `app` variable:

```
helpers do
    class Middleman::Sitemap::Resource
       def link(text)
            app.link_to(text, path)
        end
    end
end
```